# Why can't I access this value/element in this associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

```
echo "<br><table><tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    if ($j == 2) echo '<tr>';
    echo    '<td width="50%" valign="top"><strong>' . $row['name'] .
            '</strong><br><strong>Price:</strong> £' . $row['price'] .
            '<br><strong>Stock:</strong> ' . $row['stock'] . ' units' .
            '<br><img src="upload/' . $row['imgName'] .
            '" width="100em" height="100em" /><br><br>' . $row['descr'] .
            '<br><a href="added.php?id="' . $row['P_id'] . '">Add to Cart</a></td>';
    $j++;
}
```

The element in question is

> $row['P_id']

Background info on P_id:

- It is a primary key for the products table
- I can't even echo its value?

**EDIT**

As requested :)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodGroup='$prodGroups[0]'"; // GET PRODUCTS FROM FIRST PRODUCT GROUP
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**EDIT**

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE products (
    P_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL KEY,
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(5,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    descr TEXT,
    imgName VARCHAR(50),
    stock INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    prodGroup VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)";
```

Comment: Can you show us the query that generates `$result`?

Comment: Don't forget that it is case sensitive. Basically, there must be a typo

Comment: I wish there was a typo!

Comment: Do all the other `$row[]` values echo properly?

Comment: Yes they echo fine, as expected.

Comment: Can you post your table structure for `products`

Comment: 1) mysql_* methods are deprecated, you really shouldn't use them. mysqli_ or mysql_pdo are the way to do. 2) you don't seem to be closing any <tr> tags, just opening more of them - you might want to ix that. 3) Should it be p_id instead of P_id? 4) If you still haven't found the answer, add an 'if (!isset($result['P_id])) die(var_dump($result))' in your while loop, and examine the output to see what's going on.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row);` output?

Comment: @TasosBitsios I'm aware of the <tr> issue, I'm yet to get round to that. I'm also aware of mysql_ & mysqli_. This isn't going public.

Comment: @Sean Product table added :)

Comment: i think it should be <a href="added.php?id=' . $row['P_id'] . '">Add to Cart....  there shouldn't be a " before ' which is in front of the $row

Comment: @BarışAkkurt That is incredible that you noticed that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the " right after id= and try it again.

```
<a href="added.php?id="' . $row['P_id'] . '">Add to Cart</a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="added.php?id=' . $row['P_id'] . '">Add to Cart</a>
```

Comment: If this doesn't fix the problem, it still helped ;) Good eye @kenkell